# Keeping menu or preview showing for longer on Nikon D5100

Tags: nikon-d5100

My D5100 will constantly put the screen to sleep while I am busy using it. Is there a way to extend the amount of time the menu or preview screens will remain visible before the screen switches off?

Comment: there is no Auto Off Timers option!

Answer (score 4):

To change the duration the screen stays on for you will need to set the time out in the menu.

Menu > Custom Settings Menu (Pencil Icon) > Auto Off Timers.

In this menu you can change the time out in seconds.

If you need the INFO overlay to stay on you can change this in the menu under "Auto image display".

Leaving the LCD screen lit longer will affect battery life, by how much is open to debate but just bare it in mind.

Source: 5100 owner with camera sitting on my lap.

Comment: I can't see a menu item called "Auto Off Timers" in the Custom Settings Menu.

Comment: @Nippysaurus - *Custom Settings -> c Timers/AE Lock -> Auto Off timers*. If you do not see it, check if you have the latest firmware of the camera. If you still do not see it, try in one of P, A, T, M mode since sometimes more automatic modes hide menu options.

Comment: On my dad's D5100, I see it (option C2 under the pencil icon – not the wrench) even in the auto and scene modes. He's never done a firmware update and bought the camera when it was just released.

Comment: @mattdm - Thanks for checking. I was just covering my bases since I no longer have a D5100 with me.